# Consulta en mysql, calculo de tiempos de ejecución

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con esta estructura

```
CREATE TABLE ESTADOS (ID, FECHA, OFF,FC,PCM,AA,EMERGENCIA).
```

El `id` es un entero, la `fecha` es de tipo `DATETIME`, y el resto de campos son `0` o `1`.

Básicamente representa en cada momento que dispositivo está funcionando. Por cada fila solo puede ser 1 uno de los campos de `OFF,FC,PCM,AA,EMERGENCIA`, el resto deben de ser `0`.

Cada vez que se produce un cambio de dispositivo se introduce una nueva fila en la tabla, tal que así

```
ID  fecha   OFF FC  PCM AA  EMERGENCIA  Estado 
1   2020-06-26 09:46:02     1   0   0   0   0 
2   2020-06-26 09:46:49     0   1   0   0   0   
3   2020-06-26 09:48:20     0   0   1   0   0
```

A posterior, me solicitan que calcule el tiempo que está funcionando cada dispositivo, pero no puedo modificar la tabla, sino añadiría un campo con un contador de tiempos.

Intenté hacer un disparador para que cada vez que existe una inserción en la tabla, compruebe a que dispositivo está activando y entonces que haga un `DIFF(fecha,now())`, pero no funciona correctamente y la verdad que no termino de poder ver como puedo solucionarlo sin modificar la tabla.

Gracias y saludos.

Gracias incorporo lo que intenté para resolver. Crear una tabla intermedia con este `SELECT`

```
SELECT SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento.ID, SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento.OFF, SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento.fecha, TIME_FORMAT(TIME(SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento.fecha), '%H:%i')
FROM `SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento`
WHERE SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento.OFF = 1
group by SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento.fecha
```

Con esto consigo almacenar todos los estados `OFF` con sus horas de comienzo, pero ahora según entiendo debería recorrer dicha tabla para ir restando las horas para poder saber cuanto tiempo realmente está funcionando.

Me voy a responder a mi mismo, para ver si ayudo a más personas, al final me decidí por crear una `VISTA` a través de un `SELECT`. Coloco el código directamente de la consulta

````
FROM (SELECT t1.ID, t1.OFF, t1.fecha, t2.fecha AS fechaFin, t2.fecha - t1.fecha AS duracionSeg
FROM SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento t1
LEFT JOIN SOLENVERestadofuncionamiento t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID + 1
WHERE t1.off  = 1) x
GROUP BY DATE(x.fecha)```

Con esto se agrupan por días
````

Comment: Por favor, incorpora el dataset y el código que has intentado a tu pregunta

Comment: No esta claro como se relaciona el mismo dispositivo que esta en off-on en los registros de la tabla. Sabiendo eso se puede usar las funcion TIME_TO_SEC para convertirlos a segundos y calcular la diferencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias F.Igor, efectivamente tienes toda la razón, no hay una relación entre el estado on-off. Ese es el gran problema que no lo hicieron a la hora de definir la base de datos, la única relación, por llamarla de alguna forma, es que cada insercción en la tabla se produce cuando existe un cambio de estado en alguno de los dispositivos, es decir, si está activo el flag AA y se produce un cambio a PCM, se produce una entrada en la tabla.